# How can I export Mosaico html without tabulation?

Tags: email, mosaico

I'm trying to export emails I've created in a way that can be pasted into an already existing webpage, but it seems impossible as Mosaico utilizes tables to display information. Is it possible to export the email templates without tabulation? I'm trying to do this so that I don't have to format the information twice.

Comment: Do you know that you can set Mailings to be 'public' in which case they are available at a url?

Comment: eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/mailing/view?id=2

Answer (score 0):

You could try something an [online utility](https://html-cleaner.com/) that strips table tags from HTML and paste in your Mosaico mailing HTML. If you're just looking for basic text formatting like headings, paragraphs, bold, bulleted lists and so on, that might work, but if you have more complex formatting, I suspect you might not find that's a great solution. Worth a try though!